# Django-MSSQL error when creating a user from the admin panel

Tags: python, sql-server, django, transactions

I am a bit stuck, my app is nearly finished and I have a problem, I can't create a user with the admin panel.

I am using django 1.9 and MSSQL and when I go to my admin panel (with a superuser I created in the shell), I have my groups and my users, I can enter them both, but when I want to  add a user it gives me this error :

> (-2147352567, 'Une exception s\x92est produite.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE
>   DB Provider for SQL Server', u"Impossible d'ex\xe9cuter SAVE
>   TRANSACTION quand aucune transaction n'est active.", None, 0,
>   -2147467259), None) Command: SAVE TRANSACTION [s6736_x1] Parameters: []

The translation is :

> (-2147352567, 'An exception has happend.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB
>   Provider for SQL Server', u"Impossible to execute SAVE TRANSACTION
>   when no transaction is active.", None, 0, -2147467259), None) Command:
>   SAVE TRANSACTION [s6736_x1] Parameters: []

When I try to add a group I have no problem, I can access the group creation form.

If anyone has an idea I would be thanksful.

Here is my traceback :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/add/

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'reception']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error, I just modify my SQL provider from : "SQLOLEDB" to "SQLNCLI11"

There  is an error on the django-mssql website in the "read the docs", it is written that the default provider is SQLCLI10, which is true and it but this provider does not exist, it is SQL**N**CLI10.

And now it works perfectly.